# Вопросы к паттерну Builder

Tags: java

Как можно реализовать грамотно паттерн Builder, чтобы у меня hasmMap заполнялись значениями.

Условно я пишу такой код:

```java
        Arguments arg = new ArgumentBuilder();
        arg.addArgument(Argument.of("command:myCommand", "reload")
                        .addArgumentHint("reload", "hint 1"))
                .addArgument(Argument.of("argument:reload", "console")
                        .addArgumentHint("console", "hint 2"))
                .build();
```

и после этого у меня создается определенный обьект Argument с двумя hasmMap.
addArgument записывает в одну мапу, а addArgumentHint записывает в другую.

Прикрепил примерную структуру как это должно выглядеть.
(Т.е если уже введен аргумент create, то delete не может показываться, это все как бы отдельные иерархии)

[image: пример]

Comment: Не совсем понял Ваш вопрос, но из того, что понял и если следовать предоставленному Вами коду... Создаёте класс ArgumentBuilder, в котором у Вас будет логика создания объекта и метод addArgument принимающий параметром экземпляр Argument и возвращающий ссылку на самого себя. Класс Argument статическим методом of создаёт экземпляр Argument и возвращает ссылку на него. В этом-же классе Argument метод addArgumentHint.

Comment: Мне скорее нужна четкая иерархия..

Comment: Отредактируйте Ваш вопрос так, чтоб пример кода соответствовал примеру структуры. В примере структуры укажите, что должно являться ключом, а что значением. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос или добавить в него уточняющие детали, т.к. в текущем виде он не однозначно описывает Вашу проблему/задачу. Также, не совсем понятно по каким причинам Argument и ArgumentHint должны быть в разных map'ах. Почему нельзя обойтись одним классом и map'ом?